# not able to get the bean which is created in another 3rd party spring boot lib

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection

I have a spring boot app in which I have added another library (in pom.xml).

This library is also a spring boot library which has created some beans and made the beans available using @Bean. The code snippet in 3rd party library is like this  :

```
@Bean
public CustomObject customObject() {
    return new CustomObject();
}
```

Now, I am using this library in my application, but I dont see this bean registered with my application.
I checked all the beans registered with application Context and also tried loading from application context. But no luck.

What am I missing here? The purpose of this 3rd party library is to check some config and create this bean, so if I have to manually create this bean, it takes away the whole purpose.

Comment: Is this bean is in under component scan?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal, amidst of all the analysis, this is what I missed. After adding, the package of the class which I saw after decompiling the jar, I could get the bean. I think the 3rd party library should provide all this details. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Good to hear that issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @Rohit in comments, I missed to add the package of the class in the 3rd party lib jar under  component scan. After adding the package under component scan, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is information is not enough, can you please share your pom file of library that contains CustomObject.

I need to see pom file build section code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).